# C# Coded UI Tests - How to get full URL from WinTabPage-object?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, coded-ui-tests

In my test I want to open a new tab in IE and validate that the correct url is shown in the new tab.

To get the tab-object I'm using the BrowserWindow-object (which returns a list of all open tabs):

`WinTabList tabList = new WinTabList(browserWindow);`

Then I identify the correct tab using the ToolTipText-property from the Tab-object which is of the type WinTabPage:

```
string url = newTab.ToolTipText; // Ugly but works to get truncated version of the URL with "..." at the end
```

But I only get a **truncated version** of the URL...

Is there a way the get the **full** URL from the WinTabPage-object?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking more for the .Uri property from the BrowserWindow rather than the tab.  To get the property of the new tab, you'll first need to `.Locate()` the new tab using the tab's title and set it to a new `BrowserWindow` object.

```
BrowserWindow secondTab = browserWindow.Locate([tab title]);
```

Now, you should be able to get the .Uri of the new tab and make your assertion.

```
string location = secondTab.Uri.ToString();
Assert.AreEqual(location, expectedUrl);
```

When necessary, you can dispose of the `secondTab` object, and your `browserWindow` will remain as it's a new instance of the object type.

Comment: I still don't know which property has the full URL? (If there exists any) 
I tried getting the browserWindow.Uri but it returned the URL from the first tab...

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it to explain the method for changing focus.